# what is the use of timezone in datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datetime

I am using Datetimepicker for date and time input. But i am not able to understand what is the use of timezone option in it. I mean when i submit the input to datetime datatype in mysql and then select back what changes i am going to face because of timezone. I am not able to get it. Please help me. I am using this code for datetimepicker.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({  
      showSecond: true,
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' ,
      timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
     showTimezone: true,
     LocalTimezone: false,  
      stepHour: 1,
      stepMinute: 1,
      stepSecond: 10

     });  

  });
```

Comment: I don't know, but why don't you just try it out? And which "timezone" option do you mean: `showTimezone` (I'd guess this one just shows the name of the timezone in the UI) or `LocalTimezone` (is the capitalization in this one correct?)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this

"showTimezone?: boolean; //Default: null - Whether to show the timezone selector not when selecting the date picker".

for more details please use this
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery.ui.datetimepicker/jquery.ui.datetimepicker.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

not because of `timezone` but your `dateFormat` set doesn't match `datetime` type in your database.

try set `dateFormat` to `YYYY-MM-DD`